# iPhone UIImagePicker Camera in Landscape Orientation

Tags: iphone, camera, orientation, landscape

Is there any good way to set `UIImagePicker` to landscape orientation? I tried to call `setStatusBarOrientation` after `presentModalViewController` like following,

```
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight animated: NO ];
```

However, the video duration view (00:00) on the right corner didn't rotate as orientation changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), the image picker only supports portrait mode.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't support landscape for camera view. If you want anything shown as customised then add overlay view on it & transform that view to look as landscape view.
@Note:-overlay is also add as portrait thats why transformation needed.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create landscape camera view using the following code:

```
[self.view insertSubview:self.imagePicker.view atIndex:0];

self.imagePicker.view.transform =  
    CGAffineTransformScale (
                            CGAffineTransformTranslate(
                            CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2), -90, -15),
                            1.2,1.2)
                            ;
```

Note that I am directly adding the imagePicker's view to the current view, not calling it as a modal.

`self.imagePicker.view.transform` seems to respond as expected to all `CGAffineTransform` function calls, though I can't speak to whether or not Apple approves of this method.