# How to change the UIImage picker camera orientation to landscape?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios5, ios6, ios7

I am newbie in IOS.I working on the demo project in which I am supposed to open UIImagepicker to pick photos and Camera to capture new one, in all orientation. **I know UIImagepicker supports only portrait orientation**, but I have made a category class of UIImagePicker and in which i override the orientation methods to support orientation.

The issue is my UIImagePicker gets open perfectly in all orientation but the camera gets rotated 90 degree and comes in half screen when i change to any landscape mode.

So to solve this issue I added one observer which fires a notification when orientation changes.

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

And the method which is called is

```
- (void) orientationChanged
  { 
    if (self.imagePickerController.sourceType==UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera)
    {

    @try {

             if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
            {
                transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,LANDSCAPE_NEGATIVE_ANGLE * M_PI / LANDSCAPE_ANGLE);
                transform=CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -75, -80);
                [self.imagePickerController setCameraViewTransform:transform];

            }
            else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
            {
                transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,LANDSCAPE_NEGATIVE_ANGLE * M_PI / LANDSCAPE_ANGLE);
                transform=CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 75, 80);
                [self.imagePickerController setCameraViewTransform:transform];

            }
            else
            {
                //        CGAffineTransform tmpTransform=PORTRAIT_Transform;
                transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(transform,LANDSCAPE_NEGATIVE_ANGLE * M_PI / 90);
                transform=CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, 0);
                [self.imagePickerController setCameraViewTransform:transform];

            }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"Exception occured, Details :%@",exception);
    }
    @finally {

    }

}
```

}

This method works fine for me when I open camera in portrait mode and then I change to other orientation. But when I open the camera in landscape mode all things mess up.
I know i used static values here but I didn't had any other choice.

Does anyone have any suggestion or alternative option. I will be really thankful to him/her.

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 1):

These answer can help you :

[iPhone UIImagePicker Camera in Landscape Orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951315/iphone-uiimagepicker-camera-in-landscape-orientation)

or

[iOS UIImagePickerController result image orientation after upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427656/ios-uiimagepickercontroller-result-image-orientation-after-upload)

Nice way to do this.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, the first link says it is not possible technically...that i know, while the other answer talks about UIImage not about UIImgePicker Camera !!! Thanx for concers

Comment: The Image captured from the camera is coming perfectly.But the issue is the camera overlay view gets messed up !!!